# Is it possible to reference other scripts in a TSQL script file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

like C file, add reference in a SQL script file at beginning?

```
#include "somefile.sql"

-- other code...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running them with [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)  you can use `r:` to include other scripts

```
:r C:\Files\selectFromTable.sql
```

[Editing SQLCMD Scripts in the Transact-SQL Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833281%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: we are not use sqlcmd directly, use MS SQL Server Management Studio. But i learned a new way, thanks.

Comment: your solution is 'new' way. :)